# catch the point in swift and core graphics

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, core-graphics

I am making a drawing app , using swift

the drawing app its all about connected lines ,
I have in array store all first touch and the last touch , so I want when the user press in view the start touch will be the closer point from the array :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var drawingPlace: UIImageView!

    var startTouch : CGPoint?
    var finalTouch : CGPoint?
    var storePoints : [CGPoint] = [] // this will store the first touch and the last touch

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace) //
        if startTouch == nil{
        startTouch = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)
            storePoints.append(startTouch!)
        }else{
            for point in storePoints{

                if location == point { // i want to say if location == point or near the point
                    startTouch = point // so the start touch equal the point   
                }  
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        finalTouch = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)
        storePoints.append(finalTouch!)
        if startTouch != nil{
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingPlace.frame.size)
            drawingPlace.image?.draw(in: drawingPlace.bounds)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            context?.beginPath()
            context?.move(to: startTouch!)
            context?.addLine(to: finalTouch!)
            context?.strokePath()

            let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            drawingPlace.image = img

        }
    }

}
```

the problem is :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace) //
        if startTouch == nil{
        startTouch = touch?.location(in: drawingPlace)
            storePoints.append(startTouch!)
        }else{
            for point in storePoints{

                if location == point { // i want to say if location == point or near the point
                    startTouch = point // so the start touch equal the point
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want if the location touch is around any point of the storePoints array , then the startTouch Will be equal the point .

any idea I will be thankful .

mazen

Comment: What problem are you having? Are you crashing? Please clarify your problem.

Comment: @RoboticCat every thing is alright , but I want when the user press in view the start touch will be the closer point from the array

Comment: @RoboticCat please check the touchesBegin function comment .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way to do this but it's solve the problem 75% , the code :

```
func catchPoint(points : [CGPoint] , location : CGPoint){
        let qal = points[0].x - points[0].y
        for point in points{

            let x = location.x - point.x
            let y = location.y - point.y

            if abs(x) + abs(y) < abs(qal){
                startTouch = point
            }
        }
    }
```

why 75% , because : when the array have too much points its get harder to catch the point **still don't why** .

hopefully the code help someone.